# Disabling ssh password authentication (client side) does not seem to work, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: ssh, passwords, openssh

I was looking for a way to disable password authentication in the OpenSSH ssh client, in a way that it only tries public key login and if that fails would simply not connect, and that it would never show a password prompt (also implying that it would not do any interaction in the case of a login failure). There is an option PasswordAuthentication that one can set with the -o parameter, so I would expect this to work:

ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no randomusername@somesshhost

However it doesn't. It still shows the "Password:" prompt and asks for a password. Why not? It seems this option is not doing what one would expect it does (but I find nothing in the man pages to explain why).

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on [unix.se] or [su]. When you do, try running ssh with the `-v` flag to print debugging output, and include the output in your question.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1022682/141 might help here.